# How to redirect to my play store app listing in Android

Tags: android, redirect, google-play

i am developing an app in which i added a button named "More Apps", what i want is when user click on that button it should redirect to the play store showing app listing of my account.
i did the following code :

```
String url_more_app = "https://play.google.com/store/search?q=rajesh%20panchal&hl=en";  
case R.id.btn_more_app:

  Intent viewIntent =
  new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
  Uri.parse(url_more_app ));
  startActivity(viewIntent);

break;
```

but when clicking on that button its showing app listing of my apps as well as apps by others,
how can i display only my apps??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change URL from

```
String url_more_app = "https://play.google.com/store/search?q=rajesh%20panchal&hl=en";
```

TO

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Rajesh+Panchal
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look this

```
final String appPackageName = "com.example"; // Can also use getPackageName(), as below

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
```

[Google Doc](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html)

Answer (score 1):

Launch Google Play Store works fine with some Market URI:

```
String market_uri = "https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:maven&hl=en";  

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(<market_uri>));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
```

where uris can be

- market://details?id=
- market://search?q=pub:

like [mine](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:maven&hl=en)